# InDesign: Offsetting 4-digit year values to the left of main body text

Tags: adobe-indesign, cc-2015

I want to create a list style where there is custom text in the front and then a text with some offset so it looks like:

[image]

The example here is made by hand (With tab on every line). Which is very stupid because I lose all the `-` at the end of the unfinished words.

How would I have to create a text style wich makes this possible. I assume this is some sort of list style with a prefix? Or is this not possible automatically?

Thank you

Comment: Not very clear, can u please tell me if you used 2 columns here or u depended throughout on tabs?

Comment: Indent, with a negative indent on the first line, ought to be enough.

Comment: Yeah these are two columns. But what I mean is the indent between th year numbers and the text.

Comment: Why is this downvoted? This is a legit question. Maybe the formulation isn't the best but nonetheless I'd say this is valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using indents as seen in my image below. Basicly you need a value in the `Left indent` field (15mm in my example, but feel free to play with this), then the same but *negative* value in the `First Line Left indent` field. And you need to manually insert a `Tab` character between your blocks.

The 15/-15mm values can be included in your Paragraph style, however you will need to insert the `Tabs` by hand, or via `GREP` Find/Replace if you have many `Tabs` to insert.

*Losing all the `-` at the end of the unfinished words*: i assume this means hyphenation, in which case i don't see how this relates to your formatting question. This will be a separate formatting issue which you need to consider when building your styles. Personally i will always avoid hyphenation unless the client really insists on using it.

[image: left indent indesign]

Answer (score 1):

Try using Tabs.

Here's how they work.
https://helpx.adobe.com/indesign/using/tabs-indents.html

There's an example which is pretty close to what you're trying to achieve.